# How to call for multiple functions

Tags: python

I have program that checks wheter a social security numer is valid or not. Right now the program is One big function that step by step checks the number i input for several anomalies.

I want to make this big function into several different ones but i have no idea how and also no idea how to call all functions in a row couse they will rely alot on the previous functions results. im gonna try to show how is looks like:

```
#i want to make this into a separate function
def numberchecker(number):
    if number > 15:
        print('bad')

#i want to make this into a separate function
    number1 = number.replace('-', '')
    number2 = number1.replace(' ', '')

#i want to make this into a separate function
    month= int(number1[2:][:2])
    if month > 13:
        print('very bad')
```

how shall i do this when some of the functions will rely on each others variables :/

Comment: Is `number` an actual number (int or float), or a string. Your code is using it as both.

Comment: Why would you compare string with a number?

Comment: You can use a class with different method and common attributes.

Comment: ah ye well its just an example the code is quite long so i just made some things up to try to show what i mean, dont mind it :D

Comment: hm is there any easier way then using a class? like is there any way to return some new variable and us it when i call the next function or something like that?

Comment: if you need anything from func1 in func2 send it as argument or you can use global variable too.My thinking. Maybe there is better approach too

Comment: how do i send something from func1 to func 2 if i dont wanna use a global variable?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm
check this link

Answer (score 1):

Your first part is already a function, but confuses numbers and strings:

```
def check_num(num):
    return num <= 15
```

your second part into a string-processing function:

```
def process_num(num):
    return str(num).replace("-", "").replace(" ", "")
```

and the third into a boolean function

```
def correct_month(str_num):
    return 1 <= str_num[2:4] <= 12
```

Now string them together:

```
if check_num(num):
    str_num = process_num(num)
    if not correct_month(str_num):
        print('very bad')
else:
    print('bad')
```

The crucial part of what you are trying to do is to `return` a value (in these cases, two booleans and a string) at the end of the function, so other functions can carry on and use it.

Answer (score 0):

If all you do is validation,  have all functions return either True or False,  for example:

```
def numberchecker (number):
    return number > 15
```

Then you can do:

```
all([numberchecker, current_month, ....])
```